# Render view as landscape PDF in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf, mpdf

I am looking to render certain views in CakePHP v2.3.6 as a printable PDF file served to the browser. I have tried the plugins

- [cakephp-dompdf-view](https://github.com/fdeschenes/cakephp-dompdf-view)
- [CakePdf](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf)

The first one was easier to set up, gave me no errors and is almost perfect for what I'm looking for.

The problem is that neither of them display pages in landscape regardless of what settings I use on either.

I did manage to use [the following guide](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/segy/2012/01/19/mpdf_component_for_generating_pdf_files_from_html) to create a landscape PDF file using Mpdf but this method involved calling a WriteHTML method in the controller which would have resulted in messy code and also breaks MVC. I much prefer the previous plugins as they convert a .ctp file into PDF which is much neater.

Comment: have you checked this tutorial?
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf is a great plugin to generate PDF files with CakePHP, but it can be sometimes hard to configure in order to achieve the exact desired result.

Be sure to render your PDF giving the right paperOrientation in your $params (as explained [here](https://github.com/fdeschenes/cakephp-dompdf-view/blob/master/View/PdfView.php)) or to modify inside the Dompdf plugin directory: View/PdfView.php the render() function, and change the default paperOrientation to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I use this Vendor class [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/) which is almost perfect.

and if you can install script into the server [wkthmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is the best. You can use it with this [Component](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jwswart/2010/04/09/wkhtmltopdf-component)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use mpdf and render landscape with this

```
// Define a Landscape page size/format by name
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
```